# Wix only registers one Service even though I declare 3

Tags: windows-services, wix, windows-installer

My .wxs file has a piece like this

```
<Directory Id="UDPMonitorFiles" Name="UDP Monitor">
  <Component Id="UDPMonitorFiles" Guid="*">
    <File Id="UDP_UDPMonitor.exe" 
          Source="$(var.UDP Monitor.TargetDir)\UDP Monitor.exe"/>
    <File Id="UDP_UDPMonitor.exe.config" 
          Source="$(var.UDP Monitor.TargetDir)\UDP Monitor.exe.config"/>
    <ServiceInstall
        Id="UDPServiceInstaller"
        Type="ownProcess"
        Vital="yes"
        Name="DiskManagement"
        DisplayName="Epicentral UDP Monitor"
        Description="Epicentral UPD Printer Monitoring Service"
        Start="demand"
        Account="LocalSystem"
        ErrorControl="ignore"
        Interactive="no">
    </ServiceInstall>
  </Component>
</Directory>
<Directory Id="S2SCallerServiceFiles" Name="S2S Caller Service">
  <Component Id="S2SCallerServiceFiles" Guid="*">
    <File Id="S2SCallerService.exe" 
      Source="$(var.S2SCallerService.TargetDir)\S2SCallerService.exe"/>
    <File Id="S2SCallerService.exe.config" 
      Source="$(var.S2SCallerService.TargetDir)\S2SCallerService.exe.config"/>
    <File Id="S2S.xml" 
      Source="$(var.S2SCallerService.TargetDir)\S2S.xml"/>
    <File Id="S2S_log4net.dll" 
      Source="$(var.S2SCallerService.TargetDir)\log4net.dll"/>
    <ServiceInstall
        Id="S2SCallerServiceInstaller"
        Type="ownProcess"
        Vital="yes"
        Name="DiskManagement"
        DisplayName="Epicentral S2S Caller Service"
        Description="Epicentral S2S Caller Service"
        Start="demand"
        Account="LocalSystem"
        ErrorControl="ignore"
        Interactive="no">
    </ServiceInstall>
  </Component>
</Directory>                         
<Directory Id="HealthWatcherServiceFiles" Name="Health Watcher Service">
  <Component Id="HealthWatcherServiceFiles" Guid="*">
    <File Id="HealthWatcherService.exe" 
      Source="$(var.HealthWatcherService.TargetDir)\HealthWatcherService.exe"/>
    <File Id="HealthWatcherService.exe.config" 
      Source="$(var.HealthWatcherService.TargetDir)\HealthWatcherService.exe.config"/>
    <ServiceInstall
        Id="HealthWatcherServiceInstaller"
        Type="ownProcess"
        Vital="yes"
        Name="DiskManagement"
        DisplayName="Epicentral Health Watcher Service"
        Description="Epicentral Health Watcher Service"
        Start="demand"
        Account="LocalSystem"
        ErrorControl="ignore"
        Interactive="no">
    </ServiceInstall>
  </Component>
</Directory>
```

That somehow only registers one service even though there are 3 projects with their own  entry.  If I comment out the one which installs (HealthWatcherServiceInstaller) then S2SCallerServiceInstaller is registered instead.

Any ideas how this could happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ServiceInstall/@Name attribute is the name of the service.  You have set all of the services to have the same name.  You need to specify different names for each service.